# How to deploy two react apps to two different paths using firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have two react web apps (both created using create-react-app) and I would like to deploy them to the same domain on different paths.  For example:

myapp.firebaseapp.com/auth
myapp.firebaseapp.com/main

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

After searching around in the docs on Firebase under the hosting tab I was able to turn up some suggestions. I believe a **Cloud Function** might be the best solution for you to accomplish what you're saying (dynamic routing based on the URL).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

*From the link:*

> Create an HTTP function to your Hosting site Open /functions/index.js
>   in your favorite editor and replace its contents with the following
>   code. This will create a simple HTTPS function named bigben.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const hours = (new Date().getHours() % 12) + 1 // london is UTC + 1hr;
  res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <title>Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      ${'BONG '.repeat(hours)}
    </body>
  </html>`);
});
```

> Direct Hosting requests to your function With rewrite rules you can direct requests that match specific patterns to a single
>   destination. For example, to direct all requests from the page /bigben
>   on your Hosting site to execute the bigben function, you would open
>   firebase.json and add the following rewrite configuration under the
>   hosting section.

```
 {   "hosting": {
     "public": "public",

     // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"    "rewrites": [ {
       "source": "/bigben", "function": "bigben"
     } ]
 } }
```

So in your case instead of executing this bigben function you can just use a function to render your app by calling your App() function.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Cahal" />
      <Welcome name="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think zeit allows you to have up to 3 different deployments running simultaneously but what you're asking (I believe) is how to add different endpoints to your one firebase app.